# get positions of given elements in a 2d array in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array with some data, ie.

```
const data = [[   , '+',    ],
              ['+',    , '+'],
              [   ,    , '+']]
```

I'd like to get [x, y] coordinates of every element that is '+':

```
const expected = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

How can I do that in Ramda?

I knocked out some code that works:

```
const getHorizontalPosition = R.map(R.addIndex(R.reduce)
  ( (xs, el, idx) => R.equals('+', el) ? R.append(idx, xs) : xs, [] ))

const combineWithVerticalPosition = R.addIndex(R.chain)
  ( (xs, y) => R.map( (x) => [x, y] )(xs) )

pipe(getHorizontalPosition,
     combineWithVerticalPosition)(data)
```

but, as you can see, it's ugly and not very readable. How can I do this more elegantly?

[link to the code in ramda repl](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%5B%20%20%20%2C%20%27%2B%27%2C%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%27%2B%27%2C%20%20%20%20%2C%20%27%2B%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%20%20%20%2C%20%20%20%20%2C%20%27%2B%27%5D%5D%0A%0Aconst%20expected%20%3D%20%5B%5B1%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%202%5D%5D%0A%0Aconst%20getHorizontalPosition%20%3D%20R.map%28R.addIndex%28R.reduce%29%0A%20%20%28%20%28xs%2C%20el%2C%20idx%29%20%3D%3E%20R.equals%28%27%2B%27%2C%20el%29%20%3F%20R.append%28idx%2C%20xs%29%20%3A%20xs%2C%20%5B%5D%20%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20combineWithVerticalPosition%20%3D%20R.addIndex%28R.chain%29%0A%20%20%28%20%28xs%2C%20y%29%20%3D%3E%20R.map%28%20%28x%29%20%3D%3E%20%5Bx%2C%20y%5D%20%29%28xs%29%20%29%0A%0Apipe%28getHorizontalPosition%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20combineWithVerticalPosition%29%28data%29)

Answer (score 3):

As you may have noticed, Ramda does not do much with index handling.  I can't come up with a particularly nice solution.

Something like this will work, but seems much less elegant the two reducers one mentioned in a comment:

```
pipe(addIndex(map)((xs, i) => pipe(
  map(equals('+')), 
  addIndex(map)((x, j) => x && [i, j]), 
  reject(equals(false))
)(xs)), unnest)(data)
```

You can see this on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%5B%20%20%20%2C%20%27%2B%27%2C%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%27%2B%27%2C%20%20%20%20%2C%20%27%2B%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%20%20%20%2C%20%20%20%20%2C%20%27%2B%27%5D%5D%0A%0Apipe%28addIndex%28map%29%28%28xs%2C%20i%29%20%3D%3E%20pipe%28%0A%20%20map%28equals%28%27%2B%27%29%29%2C%20%0A%20%20addIndex%28map%29%28%28x%2C%20j%29%20%3D%3E%20x%20%26%26%20%5Bi%2C%20j%5D%29%2C%20%0A%20%20reject%28equals%28false%29%29%0A%29%28xs%29%29%2C%20unnest%29%28data%29)**.

Comment: Wow, that's a beautiful piece of code. Elegant and easy to reason about. There's clear intention behind each line: isolate targets, inject data, remove cruft, normalize. Love it.

Comment: That's funny, as it left me very unsatisfied.  I prefer the one you suggested in https://repl.it/FiJK/1.

Comment: Well, there is mostly punctuation there. I find it rather cryptic and unbalanced. Your code is like a story.

Answer (score 1):

The elegance is with ES6 . No need for Ramda after coming of ES6.

```
const result= [];              
data.forEach((row, i) => 
   row.forEach((item, j) => item === '+' && result.push([i, j]))
)
```

Another way (without mutation + without using `var`, `const` nor `let`):

```
[].concat(...data.map((row, i) => row.map((item, j) => item === '+' ? [
        [i, j]
      ] : [])
      .filter(coord => coord.length)
     )
)
```

```js
const data = [[   , '+',    ],
              ['+',    , '+'],
              [   ,    , '+']]
   
const result= [];              
data.forEach((row, i) => 
   row.forEach((item, j) => item === '+' && result.push([i, j]))
)
              
console.log(
  result             
 )
```

Comment: Well, it can be done in ES5 using 2 for loops also, but there are two no-gos for me: state mutations and side effects. I can pluck out any of the functions in my code and unit test it in separation because the functions are not dependent on each other in any way.

Comment: got your point. answer will be updated , you will be notified

Comment: Now you can see the section of `Another way`

Comment: Nice, but I'd rather do it with two reducers: https://repl.it/FiJK/1 And since ramda has a lot more functions than ES6, I think there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an additional way to do it

```
const hasPlus = item => item == '+'
const notNull = item => item != null
const joinResults = (prev,next) => prev.concat(next);

const results = Array.from(data, (value2d, y) => {
  let indexOrNull = Array.from(value2d, (value1d, x) => hasPlus(value1d) ?  x : null);
  let indices = filter(notNull, indexOrNull);
  let indexed = map(x => [x, y] , indices);
  return indexed;
})

reduce(joinResults, [], results);
```

[Ramda Snippet](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%5B%20%20%20%2C%20%27%2B%27%2C%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%27%2B%27%2C%20%20%20%20%2C%20%27%2B%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%20%20%20%2C%20%20%20%20%2C%20%20%27%2B%27%5D%5D%0A%0Aconst%20expected%20%3D%20%5B%5B1%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%202%5D%5D%0A%0Aconst%20hasPlus%20%3D%20item%20%3D%3E%20item%20%3D%3D%20%27%2B%27%0Aconst%20notNull%20%3D%20item%20%3D%3E%20item%20%21%3D%20null%0Aconst%20joinResults%20%3D%20%28prev%2Cnext%29%20%3D%3E%20prev.concat%28next%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20results%20%3D%20Array.from%28data%2C%20%28value2d%2C%20y%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20indexOrNull%20%3D%20Array.from%28value2d%2C%20%28value1d%2C%20x%29%20%3D%3E%20hasPlus%28value1d%29%20%3F%20%20x%20%3A%20null%29%3B%0A%20%20let%20indices%20%3D%20filter%28notNull%2C%20indexOrNull%29%3B%0A%20%20let%20indexed%20%3D%20map%28x%20%3D%3E%20%5Bx%2C%20y%5D%20%2C%20indices%29%3B%0A%20%20return%20indexed%3B%0A%7D%29%0A%0Areduce%28joinResults%2C%20%5B%5D%2C%20results%29%3B%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A)

Answer (score 0):

#### Get all of the indexes then keep all the indexes where the element equals '+'.

```js
const mapIndexed = R.addIndex(R.map)

const getIndexes = (xss) => 
  R.unnest(mapIndexed((xs, i) => mapIndexed((x, j) => [i, j], xs), xss))

const data = [[   , '+',    ],
              ['+',    , '+'],
              [   ,    , '+']]

const output = 
  R.filter(R.pathEq(R.__, '+', data), getIndexes(data))

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```